# Proving a Co-Inductive property (lexical ordering is transitive) in Coq

Tags: coq, coinduction

I'm trying to prove the first example in ["Practical Coinduction"](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/papers/Structural.pdf) in Coq. The first example is to prove that lexicographical ordering on infinite streams of integers is transitive.

I haven't been able to formulate the proof to get around the [Guardedness condition](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Coinductive.html)

Here is my development so far. First just the usual definition of infinite streams. Then definition of lexicographical order called `lex`. And in the end the failed proof of the transitivity theorem.

```
Require Import Omega.

Section stream.
  Variable A:Set.

  CoInductive Stream : Set :=
  | Cons : A -> Stream -> Stream.

  Definition head (s : Stream) :=
    match s with Cons a s' => a end.

  Definition tail (s : Stream) :=
    match s with Cons a s' => s' end.

  Lemma cons_ht: forall s, Cons (head s) (tail s) = s.
    intros. destruct s. reflexivity. Qed.

End stream.

Implicit Arguments Cons [A].
Implicit Arguments head [A].
Implicit Arguments tail [A].
Implicit Arguments cons_ht [A].

CoInductive lex s1 s2 : Prop :=
  is_le :   head s1 <= head s2 ->
            (head s1 = head s2 -> lex (tail s1) (tail s2)) ->
            lex s1 s2.


Lemma lex_helper: forall s1 s2,  
        head s1 = head s2 -> 
        lex (Cons (head s1) (tail s1)) (Cons (head s2) (tail s2)) -> 
        lex (tail s1) (tail s2).
Proof. intros; inversion H0; auto. Qed.
```

Here is the lemma I want to prove. I start by preparing the goal so I can apply a constructor, hoping to eventually be able to use the "hypothesis" from `cofix`.

```
Lemma lex_lemma : forall s1 s2 s3, lex s1 s2 -> lex s2 s3 -> lex s1 s3.
  intros s1 s2 s3 lex12 lex23.
  cofix.
  rewrite  <- (cons_ht s1).
  rewrite  <- (cons_ht s3).
  assert (head s1 <= head s3) by (inversion lex12; inversion lex23; omega).
  apply is_le; auto.

  simpl; intros. inversion lex12; inversion lex23.
  assert (head s2 = head s1) by omega.

  rewrite <- H0, H5 in *.
  assert (lex (tail s1) (tail s2)) by (auto).
  assert (lex (tail s2) (tail s3)) by (auto).

  apply lex_helper.
  auto.
  repeat rewrite cons_ht.
  Guarded.
```

How do I proceed from here?  Thanks for any hints!

- **EDIT**

Thanks to Arthur's (as always!) helpful and enlightening answer I too could complete the proof. I give my version below for reference.

```
Lemma lex_lemma : forall s1 s2 s3, lex s1 s2 -> lex s2 s3 -> lex s1 s3.
  cofix.
  intros s1 s2 s3 lex12 lex23.
  inversion lex12; inversion lex23.
  rewrite  <- (cons_ht s1).
  rewrite  <- (cons_ht s3).
  constructor; simpl.
  inversion lex12; inversion lex23; omega.
  intros; eapply lex_lemma; [apply H0 | apply H2]; omega.
Qed.
```

I use the `cons_ht` lemma to "expand" the value of `s1` and `s3`.  The definition of `lex` here (with `head` and `tail`) is more close to the verbatim formulation in [Practical Coinduction](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/papers/Structural.pdf).  Arthur uses a more elegant technique which makes Coq expand the values automatically - much nicer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem with your proof is that you made the call to `cofix` too late, after `s1 s2 s3` had been introduced. As a consequence, the coinductive hypothesis that you get, `lex s1 s2`, is not very useful: in order to apply it while staying guarded, as you mentioned, we need to do it *after* having applied the constructor of `lex`. However, after doing that, we would need to show at some point that `lex (tail s1) (tail s3)` holds, where the hypothesis introduced by `cofix` can't do any good.

In order to solve this problem, we need to perform the call to `cofix` *before* introducing the variables, so that the hypothesis it produces is sufficiently general. I took the liberty of reformulating your definition of `lex`, so that it becomes easier to manipulate in such a proof:

```
CoInductive lex : Stream nat -> Stream nat -> Prop :=
| le_head n1 n2 s1 s2 : n1 < n2 -> lex (Cons n1 s1) (Cons n2 s2)
| le_tail n s1 s2 : lex s1 s2 -> lex (Cons n s1) (Cons n s2).

Lemma lex_trans : forall s1 s2 s3, lex s1 s2 -> lex s2 s3 -> lex s1 s3.
Proof.
  cofix.
  intros s1 s2 s3 lex12 lex23.
  inversion lex12; subst; clear lex12;
  inversion lex23; subst; clear lex23;
  try (apply le_head; omega).
  apply le_tail; eauto.
Qed.
```

Now, the hypothesis has the form

`forall s1 s2 s3, lex s1 s2 -> lex s2 s3 -> lex s1 s3`

which can easily be applied to the tail of our streams, as long as the resulting application is guarded.